# How can I use multiprocessing.Pool.map to process a 100GB+ file with a generator in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, bigdata, generator

How to use multiprocessing.Pool.map with very big iterable?

I need to process big file of data using multiprocessing. File size is 100GB+ so its not possible to read file in memory. So I created generator to produce data for multiprocessing.pool.map
However it loads entire file to memory.

```
import multiprocessing

def generate_data():
    with open('data.file') as data_file:
        for line in data_file:
            yield line


def run(data):
    process(data)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    pool.map(run, generate_data())
```

After running this code, I recieve Memory Error.
Looks like multiprocessing.Pool.map load all generator to Memory

How can I process generate_data() with multiprocessing.pool.map without loading it to memory?

Comment: What makes you think the entire file is loaded into memory?

Comment: Because I got memory error.

Comment: I know that pool.map uses __ len __ method on iterable, in thins way it converting it in list. However the pool.imap method or giving me memory error as well.

Comment: If any given element in `imap` takes a very long time to compute, other elements after it may continue to compute, and the results will build up in the output queue, which could also cause an out-of-memory situation. If the order of the results is not critical, you could switch to `imap_unordered` so results from the child processes are immediately available to the main process instead of queueing them to ensure correct order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a reasonable chunk size with imap, you can reduce the RAM requirement significantly.

No need for an explicit generator as the file handle is itself an iterator.

This was tested using a file comprised of 104,857,600 lines each of which is 1k - in other words, 100GB in total.

Running on macOS, no Python process were observed to exceed 4GB

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

FILENAME = '/tmp/100GB.txt'

# if the file is very large, this can be slow. You may prefer to provide an estimate
def nlines(filename):
    print('Counting lines...', end='', flush=True)
    process = Popen(['wc', '-l', filename], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, _ = process.communicate()
    print('done')
    return int(stdout.decode().split()[0])

# process each line from the file
def process(line):
    ...

def main():
    with Pool() as pool:
        with open(FILENAME) as data:
            chunksize, extra = divmod(nlines(FILENAME), len(pool._pool) * 4) #type: ignore
            if extra:
                chunksize += 1
            print(f'{chunksize=}')
            for _ in pool.imap(process, data, chunksize=chunksize):
                ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you. This pool.imap chnuksize parameter is exactly what I looking for. B.T.W. Interesting choice to use external util wc for calculating lines.

Comment: After reading your answer, I found more here: https://superfastpython.com/multiprocessing-pool-map-chunksize/

Comment: @tsurugi Using *wc* externally solves the problem of bringing the file content into Python's address space. Of course, you could use various strategies for determining a reasonable chunk size

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why a *correct* use of method `imap` (or `imap_unordered`) will still give you memory problems. So I am including code that shows how you should use either of these methods. For better performance when you have so many tasks being submitted to the pool process, you should not use the default *chunksize* argument of 1. Of course, if it's too large you could encounter memory problems even with these methods.

Please read the comments within the code.

```py
import multiprocessing

def generate_data():
    with open('data.file') as data_file:
        for line in data_file:
            yield line

def process(data):
    """
    To make multiprocessing worthwhile, this function must
    be sufficiently CPU-intensive. Otherwise, you are better off
    not using multiprocessing. The following code is actually too trival
    and will perform worse with multiprocessing.
    """
    ... # Do some processing

def run(data):
    process(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    # Since in this example our worker function, run, is not returning
    # any meaningful results, we do not care about the order in which the results
    # (None is implicitly returned by run) and imap_unordered will perform better
    # than imap. Also we just need to wait for the pool to process all submitted
    # tasks and therefore do not need to save and iterate the iterator returned
    # by imap_unordered.
    # Using the default chunksize (1) will minimize memory used but will greatly
    # increase running time. If you were using method map, the default chunksize
    # used if None is specified would be math.ceil(iterable_size / (4 * pool size))
    # where iterable size in this case would be the number of lines in the file.
    # But that might be too large based on your memory size.
    chunksize = 500 # Experiment with this value
    pool.imap_unordered(run, generate_data(), chunksize=chunksize)
    # Just wait for all tasks to complete:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

If `process_data` returns meaningful data and you need for this data to be returned in order, then:

```py
import multiprocessing

def generate_data():
    with open('data.file') as data_file:
        for line in data_file:
            yield line

def process(data):
    ... # Do some processing (transform input)
    return modified_data

def run(data):
    return process(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    chunksize = 500 # Experiment with this value
    # Assumption now is we care about the order of returned results:
    with open('results.file', 'w') as f:
        for modified_data in pool.imap(run, generate_data(), chunksize=chunksize):
            f.write(modified_data)

    # Clean up the pool:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```